# Using Spring Beans in a JMH Application

Tags: java, spring, jmh

I'm trying to use a spring context in a simple JMH application (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), but when running the benchmarks.jar it seems to have trouble reading the spring schema document even though though it works locally.

It's a standard jmh project set up from the base maven archetype. For simplicity sake:

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class BenchmarkTest {

public BenchmarkTest() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springContext.xml");
}

@Benchmark
public void benchmarkSomething() {
    // BENCHMARKS
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    BenchmarkTest benchmarkTest = new BenchmarkTest();
    benchmarkTest.benchmarkSomething();
 }
}
```

//Spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- spring beans -->
</beans>
```

When running from main there are java -jar target/benchmarks.jar
no errors, but after building the jmh uber jar and running

> java -jar target/benchmarks.jar

I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from class path resource [springContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 80; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you unzip jar and may look if the springContext.xml is there and contains exactly that what you defined?

Comment: Yes, it is in the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Adding this to my maven shaded jar plugin fixed it. H/T http://www.eorlovsky.com/2010/03/maven-shade-spring-core-handlers_27.html

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
<resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
<resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
```